# Use Yii CRON command to execute and action in a Controller

Tags: yii, cron

I have an action inside a controller MyController:

```
public function actionMyAction()
{
//To do
}
```

I also have a console command class `/protected/commands/TestMyCommand.php`

```
class TestMyCommand extends CConsoleCommand {

public function actionDoMyCommand($args) {
    $class = new MyController;
    $result = $class->actionMyAction();
}
```

}

In my yiiBase.php, I have this line:

```
                else
                include($className.'.php');
```

Which throws an error:

```
PHP Error[2]: include(MyController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

When I run this commant.

```
php /var/www/html/path/protected/yiic.php testmycommand domycommand
```

When I try calling any other php file in my shared folder, the error is not throw.
Is there a way I can execute my action without transferring the function to a file in the shared folder?

Comment: Maybe its permission issue, try to change permission to your controller to 777 (Just for test) and check if its work or no...... chmod 777 MyController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resulted to creating a `MyActionUtils.php` in the `libraries/shared` folder and transferred the logic from the controller to the file.

```
class MyActionUtils
{

public function __construct()
{

}

public function actionMyAction()
{ 
  //To do
}
```

Then I changed my command to:

```
class TestMyCommand extends CConsoleCommand {

  public function actionDoMyCommand($args) {
     $class = new MyActionUtils;
     $result = $class->actionMyAction();
   }

}
```

Then I called my cron by navigating to the folder containing `yiic.php` and running the command: `./yiic testmycommand`